# AWS lambda in VPC with 2 AZ failover strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to create lambda in VPC, also want to spin these lambda's in two different subnets in different AZ's and while failure of one AZ traffic should automatically route to different AZ. I am planning to trigger the above lambda function through API gateway. Will API gateway detect AZ failover and run lambda in another AZ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/security-resilience.html).

*High availability – Lambda runs your function in multiple Availability Zones to ensure that it is available to process events in case of a service interruption in a single zone. If you configure your function to connect to a virtual private cloud (VPC) in your account, specify subnets in multiple Availability Zones to ensure high availability.*

The API gateway itself triggers a Lambda function whenever it receives a request, currently there is no option for health check of a Lambda function, but reading above mention from AWS, it's safe to say that the AZ/health check is done inside Lambda underlying infrastructure, rather than service level.